# Code HTML into JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write some HTML code inside JavaScript

The HTML:

```
<!--start ramadan-->
<section id="ramadan" style="min-width:1200px">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="baner">
      <div class="page">
         <div class="slider">
            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
               <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                  <img src="royamotion2015/img/img/001.jpg"   title=""/>
                  <img src="royamotion2015/img/img/002.jpg"  alt="" title="" />
                  <img src="royamotion2015/img/img/003.jpg"  alt="" data=""-transition="slideInLeft" />
                  <img src="royamotion2015/img/img/004.jpg"  alt="" title="#htmlcaption" data=""-transition="slideInRight" />
               </div>
               <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
                  <strong></strong> <em> the code in view-source this page </em>  
                  <a href="#"></a>.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
<!--end ramadan-->
```

How can I write code like this JavaScript?

http://jj.org.sa/aa/1.html

Comment: incluse minimal code samples in the question directly, and do not link to it (as the link might get unusable, which makes your question useless). also please be more precise what you want, ti is unclear. also java or javascript?

Comment: JAVA the programming language is not the same as JavaScript the scripting language. Do you mean JAVA scriptlets (JSP) ?

Comment: @mplungjan: I suppose you can remove the Java tag as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking how to put that piece of code inside HTML...?

If so, it's easy. Put `<script>` tags inside your html:

```
<script>
    function url() { 
        var x = window.location.pathname; 
        if  (x=="/index/index.php") { 

        } 
    }
</script>
```

And your JavaScript code will work.

If you're saying you need to write your whole page in JavaScript, which, in my brain, is crazy, then you have to use `document.write();` and write each line of code:

```
<script>
    document.write("<section id=\"ramadan\" style=\"min-width:1200px\">");
    document.write("<div class=\"container\">");
    etc. etc.
</script>
```

Comment: Please wait until you have enough rep to comment. Do not waste space with an answer since that also blocks the OP from deleting his question

Comment: ok .. now i need to write the code html in my questions in if Condition i try to do it .. it does't working

Comment: @mplungjan and the only way to get rep to comment is to answer, right?

Comment: @Ibn_Hayyal If you're saying you need to write HTML code in JavaScript, follow my edit above.

Comment: Not only but if you post an answer, ANSWER and "I have no idea" is not a way to start an answer that will get point but a great way to lose rep

Comment: I did answer - I put two answers cause I don't know what he's talking about, and I removed the beginning sentence. Better?

Comment: This is what i want .. Thank you very much @TheJuniorProgrammer .